# How to snip part of a rows' data and only leave the first 3 digits in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

```
0    546/001441
1    540/001495
2    544/000796
3    544/000797
4    544/000798
```

I have a column in my dataframe that I've provided above. It can have any number of rows depending on the data being crunched. It is one of many columns but the first three numbers match another columns data. I need to cut off everything after the first 3 numbers in order to append it to another dataframe based off of the similar values. Any ideas as to how to get only the first 3 numbers and cut off the remaining 8 values?

So far I've got the whole column singled out as a Series and also as a numpy.array in order to try to convert it to a str instead of an object.
I know this is getting me closer to an answer but i can't seem to figure out how to cut out the unnecessary values

```
 testcut=dfwhynot[0][:3]
```

this cuts the string where i need it, but how do i do this for the whole column is what i can't figure out.

Comment: Have you tried pandas' `join`ing or `merge`ing?

Comment: Before i can join or merge the data to another dataframe i need it filtered. In order to filter it to my needs i need only the first 3 values from the data above. I plan on swapping that column with another one after it is filtered and then using .join to get it appended.

Comment: You can use `df['series'].str[:3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the name of your column is `col`, you can

```
# Split the column into two
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda row: row.split('/'))
df[['col1', 'col2']] = pd.DataFrame(df_out.values.tolist())
```

```
  col1    col2
0  546  001441
1  540  001495
2  544  000796
3  544  000797
4  544  000798
```

then get the minimal element of each `col1` group

```
df.groupby('col1').min().reset_index()
```

resulting in

```
  col1    col2
0  540  001495
1  544  000796
2  546  001441
```

Comment: Thank you this works very well! I had a feeling it would be simple, I just couldn't nail it down.

Comment: Thanks for the question! I've just changed it a bit so it's all done within a single dataframe.